# Python: Problem running concurrent incremental functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, function, concurrency

I'm working on a Cookie Clicker-like incremental game script on Mu. Where every time you input a '.' it increases a variable named 'dots' by one. However I'm having trouble running this concurrently with a function that increases the 'dots' variable by one every second.

```
import threading
import time
dots = 0

def func1():
    global dots
    while True:
        user_input = input() 
        if user_input == '.':
            dots = dots + 1
            print(dots)

def func2():
    global dots
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        dots = dots + 1
        print(dots)

func1_thread = threading.Thread(target=func1)
func2_thread = threading.Thread(target=func2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func1_thread.start()
    func2_thread.start()
```

This code results in a syntax error every alternating '.' entered by the user:

File "", line 1
.
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

*Thank you in advanced for anyone that helps me out.*

(Fixed the problem, the version of python I was running was 3.6 so I switched to pycharm on version 3.9 and it works great.)

Comment: How are you running this?  Is it from an interactive Python shell?  It seems likely that your program is taking one ‘.’, then the shell gets the next one and says it is a syntax error.

Comment: when I run it in Linux console/terminal then it works without problem.

Comment: Glen, I am running this on script.

Comment: Are you sure this is Python 3?  It seems your call to `input` is evaluating the user’s input, which it does in Python 2.

Comment: Davis, I checked on Windows PowerShell and it says it is running on version 3.9.0

Comment: Don't check from another shell, check from within your script what version of Python it is running on - it does look like you're not running in the environment you expect to be running in.

Comment: I figured out the problem, I was running it on Mu on version 3.6 so I switched to pycharm and it worked. Thank You to everyone who helped me out.